# How to add information in a page without refreshing the page?

Tags: django

I would like to have a page in my django application that has a button that search a product and after selecting quantities gets added to the page (without reloading) in a list where the total get calculated [(something like that)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czLBouELOLI), I am a beginner in programing and I have a week reading and investigated how to do it but I don't found anything.

Is because you need other programming language? Or could you indicate me some documentation or some example that I can read. Mostly because for my inexperience I don't know how to identify the relevant information in the documentation or even what to look for.

Comment: you should use Jquery & Ajax. You can find many videos about it on Youtube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using Ajax call,

check this example:

forms.py

```
class sampleForm(forms.Form):
   input = forms.CharField()
```

views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def sampleview(request):
   input = request.POST.get('input', None)
   #perform your logic here
   #let us say your data is in variable result
   result = {'product1' : 'python' ,'product2' : 'django' , 'product3' : 'ajax'  }
   return JsonResponse(result)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('sampleview',views.sampleview,name='sampleview'),
]
```

your HTML

```
    <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <button id="sampleform-submit" type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    $("#sampleform-submt").click(function(){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $('#id_input').closest("form")
        //id_input is id of input tag generated by form and above line selects the form
        $.ajax({
            url : "{% url 'sampleview' %}",
            type: "POST",
            data : form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                #data is 'result' you return in sampleview function
                $("#results").append('<p> '+ data.product1 +'</p>');
                $("#results").append('<p> '+ data.product2 +'</p>');
                $("#results").append('<p> '+ data.product3 +'</p>');                                         
            }
        });
    }      
    </script>
```

I hope this helps